# Comparing and Matching keybinds while comparing 2 tables and returning count

Tags: mysql, sql

Currently I have 2 tables, a listing table and a logs table. With the following query I'm trying to get the listings of a product on a particular day, and it returns the right output.

```
with X as (
  select l.*,
         (select status_from from logs where logs.refno = l.refno and logs.logtime >= '2021-10-01' order by logs.logtime limit 1) logstat
    from listings l
    where l.added_date < '2021-10-01')
select X.*, ifnull(X.logstat,X.status) stat20211001 from X;
```

I've tried the following in this dbfiddle(https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b0e433b59b5c4a4a0be3f0bc25d20124) with the following table for listings:

```
 (3, 'Publish','2021-05-02','2021-10-02','LP01'), (4, 'Action','2021-05-01','2021-05-01','LP02'),
 (5, 'Sold','2020-10-01','2020-10-01','LP03'), (6, 'Let','2021-05-01','2021-10-06','LP06'), 
 (10, 'Draft','2021-10-06','2021-10-06','LP05'), (11, 'Draft','2021-01-01','2021-01-01','LP04');
```

But now in my actual database, the statuses are represented by a particular keybind. For example, ('D' => 'Draft', 'A' => 'Action', 'Y' => 'Publish', 'S' => 'Sold', 'N' => 'Let'):

So basically that makes my actual listings table with the following data:

```
 (3, 'Y','2021-05-02','2021-10-02','LP01'), (4, 'A','2021-05-01','2021-05-01','LP02'),
 (5, 'S','2020-10-01','2020-10-01','LP03'), (6, 'N','2021-05-01','2021-10-06','LP06'), 
 (10, 'D','2021-10-06','2021-10-06','LP05'), (11, 'D','2021-01-01','2021-01-01','LP04');
```

Now I want a way to have the same output of my query above, but show it with the new data and instead of showing The output it is showing right now in words, it should group similar statuses and return a count for that data. For example:

| status | Count |
| --- | --- |
| Publish(Y) | 0 |
| Action(A) | 3 |
| Let(N) | 0 |
| Sold(S) | 1 |
| Draft(D) | 1 |

Basically I want something like this to be added to the statement I think:

```
SELECT case status
when 'D' THEN 'Draft'
when 'A' THEN 'Action'
when 'Y' THEN 'Publish'
when 'S' THEN 'Sold'
when 'N' THEN 'Let'
END status_l ,COUNT(*) c from listings
group by status
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you create a status table in your database. Use this table, outer join your query and count:

```
with X as (
  select 
    l.*,
    (select status_from
     from logs 
     where logs.refno = l.refno 
     and logs.logtime >= '2021-10-01' 
     order by logs.logtime 
     limit 1) logstat
  from listings l
  where l.added_date < '2021-10-01'
)
, Y as (select X.*, ifnull(X.logstat, X.status) stat20211001 from X)
SELECT 
  status.text,
  COUNT(Y.id) AS c 
from status
left join Y on Y.stat20211001 = status.code
group by status.code;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=673125506bb29b9d10719010aa2e00ae

Comment: Hey, by any chance could you also tell me how do I return all statuses as a row and thier counts under them

Comment: A query can only return pre-known columns. So, you can only query statuses known at query write time. If you add a status later, it won't be recognized. The query: `select count(case when status.text = 'Draft' then 1 end) as draft, count(case when status.text = 'Action' then 1 end) as action, ...  from status left join Y on Y.stat20211001 = status.code;`. It is usually better just to select rows instead and have your app turn them into columns dynamically, thus you will also be able to deal with statuses added later.

Comment: Hey could you kindly also have a look at this question which is related to this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69626594/showing-all-data-in-a-datewise-order-grouped-by-dates

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need in something like

```sql
with X as (
  select l.*,
         (select status_from from logs where logs.refno = l.refno and logs.logtime >= '2021-10-01' order by logs.logtime limit 1) logstat
    from listings l
    where l.added_date < '2021-10-01'),
statustable AS (SELECT 'Draft' status UNION ALL
                SELECT 'Action' UNION ALL
                SELECT 'Publish' UNION ALL
                SELECT 'Sold' UNION ALL
                SELECT 'Let')
select X.*,
       COALESCE(X.logstat, statustable.status) stat20211001
from X
LEFT JOIN statustable ON X.status = LEFT(statustable.status, 1);
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6b65365be8c3403b329a1b4b56212a03

---

> Hmm no I tried this, but it does not give the right output. The output I want is something like the table I have provided above – JJM50

My query prepares everything for final grouping - I thought that was enough...

```sql
with X as (
  select l.*,
         (select status_from from logs where logs.refno = l.refno and logs.logtime >= '2021-10-01' order by logs.logtime limit 1) logstat
    from listings l
    where l.added_date < '2021-10-01'),
statustable AS (SELECT 'Draft' status UNION ALL
                SELECT 'Action' UNION ALL
                SELECT 'Publish' UNION ALL
                SELECT 'Sold' UNION ALL
                SELECT 'Let'),
preparedata AS ( select COALESCE(X.logstat, statustable.status) stat20211001
                 from X
                 LEFT JOIN statustable ON X.status = LEFT(statustable.status, 1) )
SELECT t1.status, COUNT(t2.stat20211001)
FROM statustable t1
LEFT JOIN preparedata t2 ON t1.status = t2.stat20211001
GROUP BY t1.status
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0edec9fbd3f07892e70f7a549117af8d

Comment: Hey could you kindly also have a look at this question which is related to this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69626594/showing-all-data-in-a-datewise-order-grouped-by-dates/69626824#69626824 . You can use your query as well, since it gives the same output